# C-Statistic: Why is it calculated the way it is?

Tags: regression, logistic, computational-statistics

So, I'm taking a Binary Logistic Regression Course, and I'm modeling. Specifically we're modeling default for subprime credit accounts.

But that's neither here nor there.

I'm looking at what exactly the C-Statistic is. I understand it's the area under the ROC curve, but I'm watching a YouTube video that defines c as follows:

$$c = 0.5\left(1+\frac{C-D}{C+D+T}\right)$$

I'm trying to visualize this definition. C-D doesn't make sense to me. the concordant pairs and discordant pairs should be mutually exclusive, right? So why take their difference. That's just the number of ties.

From there, ties over the total is okay, but then why add back 1? Then take a half of that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the self-study tag.

Comment: You need to define C, D, and T if you want an answer.

Comment: I don't follow one of your claims.  Suppose there are $C=9$ concordant pairs, $D=3$ discordant pairs, and $T=1$ ties.  You appear to assert that $C-D=6$ is "just the number of ties."  Really?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a confusion between $c$ and the Somers' $D_{xy}$ rank correlation computed from $c$ using $D_{xy} = 2 \times (c - \frac{1}{2})$.  Part of this is $C - D$. $c$ is just the proportion of relevant pairs that are concordant.  This is just $\frac{C}{C + D}$ if the only ties excluded are ties on $Y$.